# Determine that XML File is FlatOPC for Word

Tags: c#, xml, vsto, flatopc

I need to determine if a Xml-File is a FlatOPC file for Word. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the one you need

```
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the file contains:

```
<pkg:package

  xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
```

So you can read the pkg:package node and check the xmlns:pkg attribute for the expected value.

Comment: This does not help, because FlatOPC-Powerpoint files also contain this element. Therefor I cannot use it as qualifier.